# Jquery basic variable swap

Tags: jquery, html, css

It seems to me that there are no errors in the code below but for some reason it won't simply change the variable value on click. Any help would be great.

```
var test = 1;

$("div").click(function() {
     test = 0;
});

if (test == 0) {
     $("p").html("hello");
}
```

I realize this is a basic question and I've searched far-and-wide but I just haven't found a solution.

Comment: It is actually changing the value of `test` when you click, but perhaps you actually expect it to set your "p" element to contain "hello"? Because that code will only run once, right after you assign your click handler (which will be before any actual clicks).

Comment: The issue is that the if statement runs when the click handler is defined. Not after it's  invoked

Comment: Can you provide some context? Where is this code? Where is it being called from?

Comment: Ahhh thanks alot. I appreciate the comments, now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement isn't within the actual click handler

```
var test = 1;

$("div").click(function() {
     test = 0;
     if (test == 0) {
         $("p").html("hello");
     }
});
```

So it wasn't actually being tested on Click.

Answer (score 0):

is it what you are looking for ?    **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2TGLH/)**

```
 var test = 1;

 $("div").click(function () {
     test = 0;

     if (test === 0) {
         $("p").html("hello");
     }
 });
```